# swift is it possible to set properties using string names and key-path-expression?

Tags: swift, swift5

I have an array of strings containing the parameters names of a class.  I wish to use this array to set the properties on a class representing the input parameters to a rest call.

However, the only way I have heard of doing it is by having the class inherit from NSObject and using the @objc attribute on the class's properties to then call

```
NSObject.setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
```

This feels kind of convoluted to force inheritance from NSObject, so I was curious if there was any other method to do the same thing using key-path-expressions

Comment: Not really, your better of using a `switch` to set the right property for each string value and I assume you also need to cast or convert the value for some properties

Comment: @James Joshua Street: Why cant you have a protocol which declares a `init` that accepts array of string as an argument and make your class confirm the protocol, and in default implementation of protocol you can set the properties of class from array.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `NSObject` inheritance, you're doing it every time you subclass UIViewController. Just go with it and rely on the good-old KVC. Also check out the `@objcMembers` attribute, it'll save you from marking each property with @objc.

Comment: I'm with Kaan, except for the "nothing wrong" part. NSObject is wrong. It wasn't wrong then, but it is now. Doesn't mean that we can get away with not using it, because we still need it for delegates, but we need to make sure we always feel unhappy about it to avoid devolving into complacency.